# getting weird printed statement in the console

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, youtube

I am embedding a youtube link in my apps like below

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frameSize inView:(UIImageView*)imageView {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html  = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frameSize.size.width, frameSize.size.height];
    videoView       = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frameSize];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [imageView  addSubview:videoView];

}
```

However, when I am playing the video and a console is throwing a long test like below to me

```
setting movie path: http://r20---sn-tt17rn7s.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?fexp=917000%2C906357%2C923121%2C914071%2C916624%2C920704%2C912806%2C902000%2C922403%2C922405%2C929901%2C913605%2C925006%2C906938%2C931202%2C908529%2C904830%2C920201%2C930101%2C930603%2C906834%2C926403%2C913570%2C901451&newshard=yes&cp=U0hVR1ZMUF9GS0NONV9ORlRDOlZKNFRXTmNDY2NS&sver=3&itag=18&mt=1362588975&id=6e1254edbdac474b&ms=au&mv=m&source=youtube&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ipbits=8&ratebypass=yes&expire=1362612211&ip=66.207.201.14&key=yt1&upn=3o0EU_taOns&cpn=6QDoUVzCQUiAeBqm&signature=C609660EDEB083FFC1ABD1F781EDA222B6F04C66.CA4A052F0E17C10D866EB3D302A258571322C185
```

I did search `setting move path` in my code but `no recored found`. Where the heck comes from and how to get rid of this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107217/uiwebview-intercept-setting-movie-path-from-javascript-audio-player and

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible way to redirect stderr into a buffer which would allow you to filter out specific messages (but personally it looks like more trouble than its worth... but on the other hand these messages could make debugging annoying): [Turn off console logging for specific objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804425/turn-off-console-logging-for-specific-objects)

Expanding on @detunized's answer (I haven't tested this yet, though):

```
bool should_show(char *buffer) {
    return !stncmp("setting movie path", buffer, 18); // untested code...
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^(void) {
        size_t const BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

        // Create a pipe
        int pipe_in_out[2];
        if (pipe(pipe_in_out) == -1)
            return;

        // Connect the 'in' end of the pipe to the stderr
        if (dup2(pipe_in_out[1], STDERR_FILENO) == -1)
            return;

        char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (buffer == 0)
            return;

        for (;;)
        {
            // Read from the 'out' end of the pipe
            ssize_t bytes_read = read(pipe_in_out[0], buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (bytes_read <= 0)
                break;

            // Filter and print to stdout
            if (should_show(buffer)) // TODO: Apply filters here
                fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, stdout);
        }

        free(buffer);
        close(pipe_in_out[1]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> setting movie path:

It comes from javascript audio player, which is in youtube.com.